# Why is a-symmetric so much harder to compute and why does it need such big keys?

Tags: public-key

I read that a symmetric encryption requires a way bigger key size to have the same security as symmetric encryption with smaller keys. But why is this, and why is it so much harder to compute?

Comment: hmm strange, it didnt found my question when i searched for in the search bar, should i delete this question then?

Comment: no need for deletion here. Just leave the question be and it will be useful as a signpost to other people.

Comment: ecc doesn't need to be "way bigger", but look at _when_ rsa/ecc/aes were invented for clues on _why_